# Concatenate a string and a variable into a variable name for Jade

Tags: javascript, string, variables, concatenation, pug

Is there a nice, clean way to **concatenate a string and a variable into a variable name** that Jade can understand?

Ideally, it would look something like this:

```
each #{shape + 'Text'} in #{shape + 'Texts'}
    li #{shape + 'Text'}
```

I tried using `window[shape + 'Text']` but that didn't seem to work. Maybe I was doing it wrong?

Here's why I want to do this:

I have an array called `shapes` that looks like this: `['square', 'triangle', 'circle']`

I'm using Jade's `each ... in ...` function to iterate through this array. Within each iteration of my function, I need to do another `each ... in ...` of one of a few other arrays. Instead of using a straight-up variable to select which array to iterate over, like `each shape in shapes`, I want to concatenate `shape` with a string in order to get something like `each squareText in squareTexts` or `each circleText in circleTexts`.

Currently, I'm using conditionals to achieve my desired result, but it's verbose and not in the minimalist spirit of the language.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So it looks like in my case, the trick is to use Javascript's `eval()` function to concatenate the variable name and the string into a new variable name. Here's my successful (and succinct) implementation.

```
- var items = eval(shape + 'Texts');
each item, i in items
    li #{items[i]}
```

Comment: Why not just use #{item} instead of #{items[i]}?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking at an option to create/eval this out of Jade, keep the jade code (and any templare for this matter) as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap a variable and string in parentheses.

```
each item, i in items
  li=(shape + 'Texts')
```

Answer (score -2):

I am not exactly following what you are referring to since I don't know `jade` at all, but you would loop through an array like this.

```
var a = ['square', 'triangle', 'circle'];
var i, l, item;
l = a.length;
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
  item = a[i];
  // At this point, you can refer to window[item + 'Text']
  // but I'm not sure what that is supposed to mean.
}
```

There is also an [Array.prototype.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) available, but I usually don't bother to monkeypatch it in to older browsers.

Comment: I understand how to loop through an array with Javascript or JQuery or whatever. What I'm interested in is concatenating a String and a Variable into the name of an already defined variable that Jade can understand.